# Copy Past footer in Word without a linebreak at the end

Tags: c#, ms-word

This Code sets the target footer to source footer, but there is a linebreak added at the end in the footer of the document. How can i remove the linebreak?

```
//quell Footer
Range sourceRngHFooter = srcWordDocument.Sections[1].Footers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range;

//target footer
Range targetRngFooter = newWordDocument.Sections[1].Footers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range;
```

Read source footer and insert it into target footer

```
//sets the target footer to source footer
targetRngFooter.FormattedText = sourceRngHFooter.FormattedText;
```

Copy Paste variant looks like this, but there is the same problem:

```
 sourceRngHeader.Copy();
 targetRngHeader.Paste();
```

I tried a lot.., this removes the linebreak but then only the text without the format is copyed.

```
 targetRngFooter.Text = sourceRngHFooter.Text.Remove(sourceRngHFooter.Text.LastIndexOf("\r"));
 targetRngFooter.Font = sourceRngHFooter.Font;

 targetRngFooter.Font.Color = sourceRngHFooter.FormattedText.Font.Color;
```

Hope someone can help me!! Thanks

Update:

[Footer should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O63XK.jpg)

But

[Looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkizU.jpg)

Comment: Why use Copy Paste instead of reading the text from the source and insterting it in the target? And why are you trying to remove the EOL from the *text* when you really want to use the FormattedText ?

Comment: That was a try, because I can't change the Text of the FormattedText and I thought I could set the format for the Text. Hope you will understand what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution

```
targetRngFooter.FormattedText.InsertXML(sourceRngHFooter.FormattedText.XML);
```

Works for me